How does electron-forge/publisher-github work?
I have my created my github token and set GITHUB_TOKEN value in my env, but I get to the "distributables" step which is strangely misspelled  and then it dies. Its like its looking for a release version 1.0.2 which does not exist. I assume this publish action will create the release? Its very unclear how this works from the docs.
✔ Loading configuration                                                                      
    ✔ Making a squirrel distributable for win32/x64 [1m17s]
  ✔ Running postMake hook
    › Artifacts available at: ..\out\make
❯ Publishing distributables
  ✖ [publisher-github] Running the publish command
    › Not Found
    › Searching for target release: v1.0.2

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
HttpError: Not Found
at ...console\node_modules\@octokit\request\dist-node\index.js:86:21
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

my repo is public, not sure what else I need to do here? The docs really don't provide much detail. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-publishing-updating
TY!

I was confused about the name and owner fields because the documentation does not fully explain that if you are using an org, then name should be the org name which was my issue here.
publishers: [
    {
      name: '@electron-forge/publisher-github',
      config: {
        repository: {
          owner: 'MyOrg',
          name: 'my-repo'
        },
        prerelease: false,
        draft: true
      }
    }
  ]

